# 2d Array length rows and column length (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

```
int[][] example = {{1,2,3},
                   {2,3,4},
                   {6,7,8}};
```

We can get the length of the column in a 2d array using example[0].length,

but how  the length of the row is determine using example.length?

NOTE : I am asking for an explanation for Why example.length is used to get the length of row? not how to get the length of columns and row in 2d array? .

Comment: Because every Java array has a fixed length... what are you asking?

Comment: Just think of a 2D Array as a **Table** with Rows and Columns: `int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];`.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like this: for a 2-D array such as `int[][] example`, the number of rows is `example.length`, while the number of columns in a row, eg. `example[0]`, is the length of that particular row, which can be expressed as `example[0].length`.

Note: the number of columns in each row can be different. For example, you could define `example` as:

```
int[][] example = { {1, 2},     // row of length 2
                    {2, 3, 4},  // row of length 3
                    {6} };      // row of length 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Java technically doesn't have 2-dimensional arrays, it has arrays of arrays.

```
 System.out.println(example.length); // number of rows
 System.out.println(example[0].length); // number of columns in first row
```

**But This could fail if:**

1. array size is 0, in which you will get an exception.
2. You are explicitly assuming that size of first element of array as size of rows, this could be ambiguous if you are taking a **Jagged array**.

**Jagged Array:** *Jagged array is array of arrays such that member arrays can be of different sizes, i.e., we can create a 2-D arrays but with variable number of columns in each row.*